# sharepoint 2019 cant see my .stp list templates in add an app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

I've creates 2 .stp with content from a SP13 server (publishing site), and uploaded them to the List Template Gallery at a SP19 server (publishing site), yet cannot find my new lists templates for creation

how can I see/create lists from .stp in SharePoint 2019 (publishing site)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any special settings/customization on the list?

In my test, after I uploaded a general SharePoint 2013(team site with enabling publishing feature) list template with content into a SharePoint 2019 team site with enabling publishing feature, I could create a new list based on the template:
[image]

You can create a new list on your SharePoint 2013 and save it as template, then download and upload it into SharePoint 2019, check if it could work.